# C# ItemNotFoundException happens while executing Get-Content "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\<file-name>"

Tags: c#, powershell

Executing Powershell query `Get-Content "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\<file-name>"` through below mentioned **C#** code returning nothing but executing the same query in Powershell console returning the data. please help me out.

**Note**: I'm running Visual Studio with ***Administrator*** privileges.

**C# code**:

```
string Query = @"Get-Content 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Adobe Acrobat Update Task'";
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.AddScript(Query);
var results = ps.Invoke();
```

**Error Message**:

```
"System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException: Cannot find path 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Tasks\\Adobe Acrobat Update Task' because it does not exist.\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ExpandMshGlobPath(String path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, PSDriveInfo drive, ContainerCmdletProvider provider, CmdletProviderContext context)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ResolveDriveQualifiedPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedMonadPathsFromMonadPath(String path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProviderContext context, CmdletProvider& providerInstance)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ContentCommandBase.ResolvePaths(String[] pathsToResolve, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, Boolean allowEmptyResult, CmdletProviderContext currentCommandContext)"
```

**Powershell Console Output for the same query**:
[image]

Comment: W10 doesn't store files in tasks.

Comment: @Vesper: this is Windows 10 PC only and files are there in Tasks folder as mentioned in the question.

Comment: What is the value of `runspace`?